# Simple AngularJS app to display current date

Tags: angularjs

I am taking an **edX course on AngularJS**. I have run into a problem with one of the labs, and they don't post solutions, plus their forum seems rather weak, so here I am.

This is the first lab in the course. All the app is supposed to do is display the following:

Module 2 Homework

> The Current Date is: “2016-05-26T16:53:22.313Z”

of course, replacing that time with the actual current time.  All I get from my program is:

Module 2 Homework

> The Current Date is: {{dateAndTime}}

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="dateTimeApp">

<head>
  <title>Date Time App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-controller="firstController">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Module 2 Homework</h1>
    <h2>The Current Date is: {{dateAndTime}}</h2>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dateTimeApp = angular.module('dateTimeApp', []);
    dateTimeApp.constant('myConfig', {dateTimeReadout: new Date()});
    dateTimeApp.controller('firstController', [
        '$scope', 'myConfig',
        function($scope, myConfig){
            $scope.dateAndTime = myConfig.dateTimeReadout;
        }
    ]);
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried the following:

```
        dateTimeApp.controller('firstController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope){
            $scope.dateAndTime = new Date();
```

I'm a bit lost here. Can someone help? Keep in mind that this is near the beginning of the course, so the answer should be very basic.

By the way, with the `h2`tag, not sure how to put Angular bit up there between quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

Your **scripts** is not closed well.

it should like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dateTimeApp = angular.module('dateTimeApp', []);
    dateTimeApp.constant('myConfig', {dateTimeReadout: new Date()});
    dateTimeApp.controller('firstController', [
        '$scope', 'myConfig',
        function($scope, myConfig){
            $scope.dateAndTime = myConfig.dateTimeReadout;
        }
    ]);
    </script> <--- here you forget to close it.
```

Comment: In the words of a famous yellow, beer-bellied, bald, donut-eating father:
D'OH!!!

I put that tag in and it worked! I can't believe it I didn't catch that. It's always the little things that get me.

Comment: @DavidTarvin :-) so maybe you can consider take this as the answer. haha~~~~

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the script, its better to put to a separate file and load the reference,

```js
 var dateTimeApp = angular.module('dateTimeApp', []);
 
dateTimeApp.controller('firstController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope){          
            $scope.dateAndTime = new Date();
   }
]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="dateTimeApp">
<head>
  <title>Date Time App</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="firstController">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Module 2 Homework</h1>
    <h2>The Current Date is: {{dateAndTime  | date:'medium'}}</h2>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for that extra credit ;)

```js
var dateTimeApp = angular.module('dateTimeApp', []);

dateTimeApp.controller('firstController', [
  '$scope',
  '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.dateAndTime = new Date();
    }, 10);

  }
]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="dateTimeApp">

<head>
  <title>Date Time App</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="firstController">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Module 2 Homework</h1>
    <h2>The Current Date is: {{dateAndTime | date:'MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss:sss a'}}</h2>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```